# How to create translucent blocks that intersect, ensuring overlapping area has same color, transparency & properties as individual blocks?

Tags: html, css, sass

How can I create two translucent blocks that intersect with each other and their crossover have the same color, transparency, and other properties?
I am trying to do clouds, but I am stuck when I tried to create translucent clouds

[image: Attempt]

I tried to use this:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child-1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 123, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.child-2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 123, 0, 0.5);
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.child-1,
.child-2 {
  isolation: isolate;
}

`
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child-1"></div>
  <div class="child child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Result of the code:
[image: this code made]

What I expect:
[image: expect]

Comment: If you want their crossover, to be the same color, transparency, etc. Just don't make them transparent. If they're transparent, of course their colors would add up, no matter what their z-index is. That's not logical to make them transparent and their colors don't add up. The only way you can do this, is if you have multiple objects that represent different parts of the shapes .e.g. (one object for cross over, and other objects to represent the outer shapes) in this case there is no crossover between the objects, but they would like two objects crossing over each other "Impractical!"

Comment: Is there a reason for not having all the children a solid color and giving their container the opacity 0.5?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. I want to create clouds for a button, where one cloud has an opacity of 1 and the other cloud has an opacity of 0.5.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding the requirement properly. What does the picture you have given show - what you want or what you don't want?

Comment: As @AHaworth said. Just add the opacity property to the parent. If your current parent is the button, then just add a new element.

Comment: Thanks for all. I already did this button, what I wanted:
https://rahunak.github.io/sun-and-moon